# I want to sum of column values when I did union or something command in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL> (select price from PC where model = '1005')

2  union

3  (select price from Printer where model = '3003');

​
    PRICE

---

```
 1999

 3599​
```

Thank you sir,
This is my code in sql. But I don't know how to make sum of this values. 
How can I sum of values when this situation?
Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You do not want `UNION`!!!  This removes duplicates, so you will not get the correct value if the price happens to be the same.  You want `UNION ALL`.

One way to do this is to move your query to the `FROM` clause and use aggregation:

```
select sum(price)
from ((select price from PC where model = '1005'
      ) union all
      (select price from Printer where model = '3003'
      )
     ) p;
```

For two scalar values, you could also just add them:

```
select ( (select price from PC where model = '1005') +
         (select price from Printer where model = '3003')
      )
from dual;
```

Of course, if either were missing, then the result would be `NULL` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer sql wich sum the values:

```
select sum(price) form (
select price from PC where model = '1005'
union
select price from Printer where model = '3003') as x
```